# IRI Mapping and referencing in JSON-LD

Tags: json, semantic-web, ontology, json-ld

I am trying to design an ontology using JSON-LD but i'm having trouble getting the syntax right. I looked at https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld but couldn't find exactly the piece of information I am looking for, which is this: How to nest IRI's in the context, and how to reference them in the body?

```
{
  "@context":{
    "@base":"http://example.com/",
    "instances":"base:instances",
    "animals":"base:animals",
    "plants":"base:plants"
  },
  "@graph":[
    {
      "@id": "instances:1",
      "@type": "Plant",
      "plants:numleaves": "8",
      "plants:speciesname": "sunflower"
    },
    {
      "@id": "instances:2",
      "@type": "Animal",
      "animals:numlegs": "4",
      "animals:speciesname": "dog",
      "animals:eats": "instances:1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want the id of the first element to be `http://example.com/instances#1`, but when I run it through http://json-ld.org/playground/ , it's expanded form is `base:instances1`. How do I make it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you want, because you define `@base` and then try to use it as a prefix.

Also the hash (**#**) won't just magically appear. You must include it in your base URI.

To sum up you would have to change your context to:

```
"@context":{
  "base":"http://example.com/",
  "instances":"base:instances#",
  "animals":"base:animals#",
  "plants":"base:plants#"
}
```

Now `instances:1` is a concatenation of `http://example.com/` + `instances#` + `1` as you ask for.